# grouping list<string> of similar type in c#

Tags: c#, list, group-by

```
.GroupBy(x => x)
```

.GroupBy is used to group string,int,etc of similar types.
Then what function can i use to group List< string> of similar type.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me.

Comment: It's quite unclear what you want, but maybe `GroupBy(x=> x.GetType())`?

Comment: Sample input, output might help here

Comment: have you read your own question. does it make sense?

Answer (score 2):

`GroupBy` relies on the element type implementing `Equals`/`GetHashCode` in an appropriate way for your aim.

Your question isn't clear, but my guess is that you want two lists with the same elements to be considered equal. I suspect you'll need to write your own `IEqualityComparer` implementation, and pass that into `GroupBy`. For example (untested):

```
public class ListEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<List<T>>
{
    private static readonly EqualityComparer<T> ElementComparer =
        EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

    public int GetHashCode(List<T> input)
    {
        if (input == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        // Could use Aggregate for this...
        int hash = 17;
        foreach (T item in input)
        {
            hash = hash *31 + ElementComparer.GetHashCode(item);
        }
        return hash;
    }

    public bool Equals(List<T> first, List<T> second)
    {
        if (first == second)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (first == null || second == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return first.SequenceEqual(second, ElementComparer);
    }
}
```

You could also allow each `ListEqualityComparer` instance to have a separate per-element comparer, which would allow you to compare (say) lists of strings in a case-insensitive fashion.

Comment: Just FYI: either change `IEqualityComparer` to `EqualityComparer` or remove the `override` modifier from the the two methods.

Comment: @NtFreX: Thanks; removed the modifier.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are asking how to group by objects of custom type.

You need to define how your objects should be compared to each other.
You can do this by specifying  `IEqualityComparer` in the `GroupBy` call.

If you don't specify `IEqualityComparer`, then `IEqualityComparer.Default` is used, which checks whether type `T` implements the `System.IEquatable<T>` interface and, if so, returns an `EqualityComparer<T>` that uses that implementation. Otherwise, it returns an `EqualityComparer<T>` that uses the overrides of Object.Equals and Object.GetHashCode provided by `T`.