# Delete row in 2D array if a column contains duplicate value

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, duplicates

I am working on a problem regarding 2D Arrays in Excel: You are able to remove rows if a single column contains duplicate values. How can I accomplish the same thing in C#?

Please see this for reference. It removes only if a whole row contains duplicate values. I need the same thing except that only if a single column contains duplicates, that row should be removed.

Link:
[Delete duplicate rows from two dimentsional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19587004/delete-duplicate-rows-from-two-dimentsional-array)

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<List<T>> ToEnumerableOfEnumerable<T>(this T[,] array)
    {
        int rowCount = array.GetLength(0);
        int columnCount = array.GetLength(1);

        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++)
        {
            var row = new List<T>();
            for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnCount; columnIndex++)
            {
                row.Add(array[rowIndex, columnIndex]);
            }
            yield return row;
        }
    }
    public static T[,] ToTwoDimensionalArray<T>(this List<List<T>> tuples)
    {
        var list = tuples.ToList();
        T[,] array = null;
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < list.Count; rowIndex++)
        {
            var row = list[rowIndex];
            if (array == null)
            {
                array = new T[list.Count, row.Count];
            }
            for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < row.Count; columnIndex++)
            {
                array[rowIndex, columnIndex] = row[columnIndex];
            }
        }
        return array;
    }
}

public class ListEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<List<T>>
{
    public bool Equals(List<T> x, List<T> y)
    {
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(List<T> obj)
    {
        int hash = 19;
        foreach (var o in obj)
        {
            hash = hash * 31 + o.GetHashCode();
        }
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var array = new[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 1, 2 }, { 7, 8 } };
        array = array.ToEnumerableOfEnumerable()
                     .Distinct(new ListEqualityComparer<int>())
                     .ToList()
                     .ToTwoDimensionalArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably build a custom `EqualityComparer` for lists with identical first/specific values.

Comment: not sure how, do u know? Not even sure this code works, borrowed from here?

Comment: The thing is, one of SO's rules is that we aren't supposed to give code to people who haven't shown a minimum understanding of how to implement things. Making an equality comparer is no more than making a class with the correct overrides and then filling in the methods with working logic, which in this case is very simple. If that isn't enough information, SO is probably not what you're looking for.