# Delete duplicate rows from Multidimensional Object array [,]?

Tags: c#, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

Let's Assume  I have Multi dimensional Object array that represents simple matrix

```
 Object[,] mybaseobject = new object[,] { 
             {"Rakesh", "Martin", "21"},
             {"Rohith", "M", "22"},
             {"Rakesh", "Martin", "21"},
             {"varsha", "MJ", "18"},
```

Even if String object[,] also fits fine for my project

It Object array looks like

```
Rakesh      Martin     21
Rohith       M          22  
Rakesh      Martin     21
Rohith       M          22
varsha       Mj         18
Rohith       M          22
```

Please find me way to delete duplicate rows and make array to look like this?

```
Rakesh      Murthy     21
Rohith       M          22
varsha       Mj         18
```

I am using this approach [one of existing approach in stack over flow forum  ][1]

[Delete duplicate rows from two dimentsional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19587004/delete-duplicate-rows-from-two-dimentsional-array)

But in abovelink works fine for Multidimensional Integer data I need solution for Multidimensional object array[,]

Please help me out thanks(+1) in advance

Comment: Why do you use 2d array? array of *custom* objects (or *anonymous* one, or at least `Tuple<String, String, String>`) is far better. If you have to deal with `String` why not *jugged* array `Object[][] mybaseobject`?

Comment: refer http://forums.asp.net/t/1721368.aspx?Removing+duplicate+multidimentional+array+entries

Comment: Even if String object[,] also fits fine for my project

Comment: Try GroupBy(x => new object[] { item1, item2, item3,......}).  Then delete everything but first item in groups.

Comment: @jdweng can you explain in detail a bit

Comment: Group by should put duplicates into one group.  The results is links back to source data.   So you should be able to remove the duplicates by the link.

Comment: @Ranju The link code is for everything, not just ints, and should solve your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you may not want to work with `object[,]`. Below is an implementation that transforms the `object[,]` to `List<object[]>`, performs filtering on that, then transforms the `List<object[]>` back to a two dimensional array.

```
void Filter()
{
    Object[,] mybaseobject = new object[,]
    { 
        { "Ranjith", "Murthy" }, 
        { "Rohith", "M" }, 
        { "Ranjith","Murthy" }, 
        { "varsha", "MJ" }
    };

    var objectList = AsList(mybaseobject);

    var distinctLines = new List<object[]>();

    foreach (var line in objectList)
    {
        if (!distinctLines.Any(x => x.SequenceEqual(line)))
        {
            distinctLines.Add(line);
        }
    }

    var filteredobjects = AsTwoDimentionalArray(distinctLines);
}

private List<object[]> AsList(object[,] input)
{
    var lines = new List<object[]>();
    for(var i = 0; i < input.GetLength(0);++i)
    {
        var line = new List<object>( input.GetLength(1));
        for (var j = 0; j < input.GetLength(1); ++j)
        {
            line.Add(input[i, j]);
        }
        lines.Add(line.ToArray());
    }
    return lines;
}

private object[,] AsTwoDimentionalArray(List<object[]> input)
{
    var result = new object[input.Count(), input[0].Length];
    for (var i = 0; i < input.Count; ++i)
    {
        for(var j = 0; j < input[0].Length; ++j)
        {
            result[i, j] = input[i][j];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on post [delete-duplicate-rows-from-two-dimentsional-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19587004/delete-duplicate-rows-from-two-dimentsional-array)
You can make list of lists and after that use custom IEqualityComparer implementation and after that get distinct values. The shortest code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mybaseobject = new object[,]
        {
            {"Ranjith", "Murthy", "21"},
            {"Rohith", "M", "22"},
            {"Ranjith", "Murthy", "21"},
            {"varsha", "MJ", "18"}
        };

        var res = ToEnumerableOfEnumerable(mybaseobject).ToList();
        var dist = res.Distinct(new SimpleComparer());

    }
    public class SimpleComparer : IEqualityComparer<List<object>>
    {
        public bool Equals(List<object> x, List<object> y)
        {
            var l1 = x[0];
            var l2 = x[1];
            var r1 = y[0];
            var r2 = y[1];
            return r1 + "" == l1 + "" && l2 + "" == r2 + "";
        }

        public int GetHashCode(List<object> obj)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<List<T>> ToEnumerableOfEnumerable<T>(T[,] array)
    {
        int rowCount = array.GetLength(0);
        int columnCount = array.GetLength(1);

        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++)
        {
            var row = new List<T>();
            for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnCount; columnIndex++)
            {
                row.Add(array[rowIndex, columnIndex]);
            }
            yield return row;
        }
    }
```

Comment: which kind of Datagrid?